# AVL failing to insert (c++)

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

I've been working on implementing a normal binary search tree as well as an AVL tree. I've got it mostly figured out, but there's one problem I can't seem to resolve. When I compile and run the driver, the insert fails. No errors on run or compile; it simply doesn't insert. I've even pasted the code from my BST insert into the insert method with the same results. I'll put the implementation below, along with the BST implementation. Any help would be perfect! Forgive me for the semi-messy code. Haven't cleaned it up well yet.

```
BST Definition 
    class BSTree {
    BSTNode *root;

    public: 
    //constructors
    BSTree();
    BSTree(int);

    //public members
    bool isEmpty(); //check if the bst is empty
    void insert(int newValue); //inserts an int into the bst. Returns success
    bool find(int findMe); //searches bst for int. True if int is in tree
    void preorder(); //calls recursive transversal
    void inorder(); //calls recursive traversal
    void postorder(); //calls recursive transversal
    int height(BSTNode *n); // given node only. 
    int height(); //returns height of whatever node is passed in. 
    int totalheight(); //returns tot height. height of empty tree = -1
    int avgheight(); //returns avg height of tree
    int totaldepth(); //returns tot depth. depth of empty tree = -1
    int avgdepth(); //returns avg depth of tree
    bool remove(int value); //deletes int. returns true if deleted

    private:
    int depth(BSTNode *n, int count); //depth of node. recursive.
    int counter(BSTNode *n); //called by other functions for counting nodes
    int totalheight(BSTNode *n); //called from public totalheight
    int totaldepth(BSTNode *n, int depth);
    int avgheight(BSTNode *n, int th);
    bool findRecursive(struct BSTNode *root, int findMe); //called from public find
    struct BSTNode* insertRecursive(struct BSTNode *n, int newValue);
    void inorderRecursive(BSTNode *n); //traverses tree in inorder
    void preorderRecursive(BSTNode *n); //traverses tree in preorder
    void postorderRecursive(BSTNode *n); //traverses tree in preorder
    };
    //----------------------Constructor---------------------------
    BSTree::BSTree(){
    root = NULL;
    } // BSTree

    //root value given
    BSTree::BSTree(int value){
    root = new BSTNode(value);
    } //BSTree(int)

    //--------------------------insert-------------------------

    void BSTree::insert(int newValue){
    root = insertRecursive(root,newValue);
    } //insert

    struct BSTNode* BSTree::insertRecursive(struct BSTNode *n,int newValue){
    //base case
    if(n==NULL)
        return new BSTNode(newValue);
    else if (newValue < n->value) {
        n->left = insertRecursive(n->left,newValue);
    }
    else if (newValue > n->value) {
        n->right = insertRecursive(n->right,newValue);
    }
    else; //duplicate: do nothing

    return n;
    } //insertRecursive

    //--------------------------Call in main-------------------------
    BSTree *t = new BSTree();
    t->insert(50);
```

Keep in mind, that works perfectly.

AVL

```
class AVLTree : public BSTree {
BSTNode *root;

public:

//constructors
AVLTree(); //given nothing
AVLTree(int value); //giving root value

//member methods
void insert(int newValue);



private:
struct BSTNode* insert(BSTNode *n, int newValue);
struct BSTNode* rotateLeft(BSTNode *n);
struct BSTNode* rotateRight(BSTNode *n);
struct BSTNode* doubleLeft(BSTNode *n);
struct BSTNode* doubleRight(BSTNode *n);
};

//--------------------------constructors-----------------------
AVLTree::AVLTree(){
root = NULL;
} // AVLTree

//root value given
AVLTree::AVLTree(int value){
root = new BSTNode(value);
} //AVLTree(int)
```

I won't show the rotate methods because even without them and the normal BST code in, it still doesn't work.

```
//------------------------------insert------------------------
void AVLTree::insert(int newValue){
root = insert(root, newValue);
}//insert

struct BSTNode* AVLTree::insert(BSTNode* n, int newValue){
if (n == NULL){ //if we are at end of tree. Insert.
    return new BSTNode(newValue);
}//if
else if (newValue < n->value) { //move left if newValue smaller than n->value
    n->left = insert(n->left,newValue);
    if (height(n->left) - height(n->right) == 2){
        if(newValue < n->left->value)
            n = rotateLeft(n);
        else
            n = doubleLeft(n);
    }//if == 2
}//else if 
else if (newValue > n->value) { //move right if newValue bigger
    n->right = insert(n->right,newValue);
    if (height(n->right) - height(n->left) == 2){
        if(newValue > n->right->value)
            n = rotateRight(n);
        else
            n = doubleRight(n);
    }//if == 2
}//else if
else; //duplicate. Do nothing.
n->height = max(height(n->left),height(n->right)) + 1;

return n;
}//insert

//--------------------call in main ---------------------------

AVLTree *a = new AVLTree();
a->insert(50);
```

Comment: Why is it so prevalent to dump code on strangers in the internet and expect it to be magically fixed? What about good old-fashioned step by step debugging?

Comment: Well I didn't know it was all that frowned upon. I've seen much worse on here before and I'm new to posting here. I was unsure how the inheritance worked and I assumed it was right because I wasn't getting errors. So debugging, which I had done, gave me nothing. And FYI, it was answered so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `root` variables.

Your `AVLTree` has its own `root` member variable, which is used in the methods of `AVLTree`.

However, the methods of `BSTree` use the `root` variable declared in `BSTree`.

Remove the unnecessary variable from `AVLTree`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I was a little confused on how the inheritance worked. I'm sorry about the mass amounts of code. I didn't realize that was a big deal here. I'm new to this